# When the Browser Refreshes the authentication token is cleared from the session storage - Springboot + Angular 9

Tags: angular, microservices, angular9

I am currently developing an application using Springboot microservices + Angular 9. I am using session storage to store my basic HTTP auth token. If I make changes in the Angular application the browser refreshes and the page doesn't log out on the browser + basic auth token is also cleared.

How should I maintain the state of the token even if the browser refreshes?

The token should get cleared when the user logs out from the application - This is my condition.

*NOTE:-* *I have used Spring Security in API gateway*

Find the below code snippet for the reference:

```
  export class AuthenticationService {
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

  public username: String;
  public password: String;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticationService(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8765',
      { 
        headers: 
        { 
          authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) },responseType : "text"  
     }).pipe(map((res) => {
              this.username = username;
              this.password = password;
              this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
      }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username)
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return false
    return true
  }

  getLoggedInUserName() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return ''
    return user
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `localstorage` instead of `sessionstorage` and clear it manually on logout event.

Comment: @SRana Its still not working. I have changed it to localStorage and after refreshing the state calls for retrieval needs the token containing the username and password to the server for further communication with the server (mainly for Receiving the data)

Comment: You are trying to `createBasicAuthToken` every time, you should check for the token in `localStorage`, if no token is in there then create a new one and set else use the older one.